# Sweet alert confirm and then save data to database

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I want to save data to the database but before that I must check name condition. If name is available it will show confirm's pop up (I use sweet alert). I already tried this code but it can't execute function for save data. Anyone can help me?

code :

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $cekname = mysql_query("select * from data_alumni where name='$name'");
 $jumlahnama = mysql_num_rows($cekname);

 if ($jumlahname > 0) {
     echo '<script>swal({ title: "Are you sure?", text: "name is available, continue save?", type: "warning", showCancelButton: true, confirmButtonColor:"#DD6B55",  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   closeOnConfirm: false }, function(){' . savedata($nama) . '});</script>';
 } else { 
     #other function 
 }
```

Comment: PHP can echo Javascript code into the page sent to the client, like you're doing, but that Javascript code can't directly call PHP code on the server, because it's run on the client, not the server.

Comment: oh ok Dan, thanks for your question.. that solved coz i use jquery ajax  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php (client side):

```
 document.querySelector('#form-input-biodata').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    var nama = $("#nama-alumni").val();
    var ceknama = 'ceknama=' + nama;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url file php",
        data: ceknama,
        cache: false,
        success: function (jumlahnama) {
            if (jumlahnama == "0") {
                form.submit();

            } else {
                swal({
                    title: "Konfirmasi?",
                    text: "Nama telah terdaftar, Ingin Melanjutkan?!",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                        function () {
                            form.submit();
                        });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

server side :

```
if (isset($_POST['ceknama'])) {
include 'connection.php';
$nama = isset($_POST['ceknama']) ? addslashes($_POST['ceknama']) : "";
$hubung = mysql_query("its my query");
$total = mysql_num_rows($hubung);
echo $total;}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your query- you have to concatenate variables using the dot operator (i.e. `.`): 
    `$ceknama = mysql_query("select * from data_alumni where nama='".$nama."'");`
2. Use Javascipt `confirm()` method after the AJAX call for interactive communication with a PHP script and the database.